printer brother
The  file /usr/lib/cups/filter/rastertobrlaser or usr/lib/cups/filter/rastertolps  seem necessary to make the printer BROTHER 1612w  work. I can't find them on line. I need help. Thanks

Title and formatting needs some improvement :)

File list of package printer-driver-brlaser in noble of architecture amd64 - see also How do I find the package that provides a file?

I’ve always been able to download the relevant drivers from the Brother website: https://www.brother.co.uk/support/dcp-1612w/downloads     Mine is a quite old device (mfc7460dn) but the downloads are all freely available.

For starters /usr/lib/cups/filter/rastertobrlaser is provided by the printer-driver-brlaser  package.
